# How to get result of child activities in a parent tab activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabview

I have Activity2 which is a TabActivity having child activities Activity3 and Activity4.Acticity2 is called from Activity1.I want results from child activity(Activity3 or Activity4) in Activity2.Any help on this...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` to start Activity3 and Activity4.
- Use `setResult` in your child activity to return data to the predecessor activity
- Use `onActivityResult` in your parent activity to receive the result from the child activity

Edit: Added bundle information. Keeping original answer as it will likely be useful for others.

Since you aren't actually starting the activity with `startActivity`, you will need to store your data from the child activities, try this:

In TabActivity:

```
// putExtra is overloaded so you can add almost any kind of data.
// First parameter is the key, second is the value
getIntent().putExtra ( "Result", "OK" );
```

In parent activity:

```
// tabAct is the TabActivity object for your tab
// Here, just specify the key that you used in putExtra in your TabActivity
String actResult = tabAct.getStringExtra ( "Result" );
if ( actResult.equals ( "OK" ) {
    // Do your actions for success
}
else {
    // Do your actions for failure
}
```

Comment: My problem is similar to this: http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/tabactivity-and-startactivityforresult-t7723.html#p26060

Comment: @RivieraKid Sir Can you please tell me How can I get the Result in my Activity You have told it in Parent Activity

Comment: @Nitin you should start a new question for this.

Comment: @RivieraKid Sir I have asked Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103518/how-to-startactivity-for-result-from-activity-under-group-activity-under-tabs